# python schedule library, run job multiple times in a day at given time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using [python schedule](http://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library as an alternative to my cron jobs. I want to schedule a job multiple times in a day which start at specific time. Currently I am able to achieve this by implementing the following code

```
import os
import schedule

@with_logging
def run_shell_script(command, extra_params=None):
    # dir_path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    os.system("sh %s" % command)

def run_threaded(command):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_shell_script, args=(command, ))
    job_thread.start()

def schedule_jobs():
    # Clenup InActive jobs from the system
    schedule.every().day.at("03:00").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('cleanup'))

    # Map JobTitles to Burning Glass std. titles
    schedule.every().day.at("04:00").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('map_std_titles'))
    schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('map_std_titles'))
    schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('map_std_titles'))

    # Copy job documents to JobsModel Collection
    schedule.every().day.at("05:30").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('copy_documents'))
    schedule.every().day.at("11:30").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('copy_documents'))
    schedule.every().day.at("17:30").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('copy_documents'))
    schedule.every().day.at("23:30").do(run_threaded, script_paths.get('copy_documents'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = get_basic_logger()
    schedule_jobs()
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

I want to invoke my copy_documents script at specific times at 5:30, 11:30, 17:30 and 23:20 hours (with a gap of 6 hours within subsequent run). Equivalent cron command for the same is

```
30 23,5,11,17 * * * bash /home/data/my-codebase/copy_document.sh
```

I wanted to know if there is a better way to do the same.

Comment: I think, even the interval job doesn't suffice your requirements. So what you could probably do is, Add the first cron job, then trace its time in the external script it calls, and later reschedule it again from the same external script. I'm not sure if this is possible in python-schedule. However this is possible in Apscheduler. That way, you can just add one job, and keep on rescheduling them automatically once the job finished.

Comment: you can use crontab for scheduling your python script on specific time interval

Comment: have you tried threading.Timer ????